# Return only rows where checking against multiple joined rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "collections" that has a comma delimited field of id's related to another table called "inspirations".

I would like to select the collection rows that contain inspirations that I can filter by a where clause. It may be easier to show an example of what I have tried:

Here is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT collections.id,collections.uid,title,inspids,private,collections.tstamp FROM collections
LEFT JOIN inspirations ON "%"+inspirations.id+"%" LIKE inspids
WHERE collections.uid = "54"
AND inspirations.keywords LIKE "%bright%"
```

This is not returning any results unless I remove the AND part. I need it to return results that match. I am probably miss-understanding LEFT JOIN, it always confuses me. The problem I'm guessing is that the LEFT JOIN is returning multiple rows, and my WHERE doesn't know how to search all of them, do I need to do a "search all left joined rows" somehow?

Or maybe there's an entirely different way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help in advance!!

---

As requested below by @Alpesh Jikadra:

collections table structure:

```
id, uid, parent, title, inspids, private, collabs, ord, tstamp
```

inspirations table structure:

```
id, uid, image, filters, caption, keywords, tstamp, thumb, stat_views, hide_from_search, ord
```

Example of data:

There are 1000's of rows in both tables so as an example:

inspirations has a row with id as "123" and keywords as "blabla,bright,yellow,happy", and collections has a row with inspids as "2074,123,42".

I would expect only collections with inspids of inspirations that contain "%bright%" in the keywords field to return.

---

Here is an SQL I used to show my problem: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f90/10

But thanks a lot to all who helped, and Daniel E for sharing the use of "find_in_set" to solve the issue, note that I had to add "GROUP BY collections.id" to only pass unique collections back, example:

```
SELECT collections.id,collections.uid,title,inspids,private,collections.tstamp FROM collections
LEFT JOIN inspirations ON find_in_set(inspirations.id, collections.inspids) > 0
WHERE collections.uid = "54"
AND inspirations.keywords LIKE "%bright%"
GROUP BY collections.id
```

Comment: Please share table structure and sample input data ,Also share expected output too

Comment: I have updated my answer.. I understand if it looks a bit cryptic :(

Comment: Please add insert query for your expected output or add into http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Sorry I've been fiddling... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f90/10
This shows the problem I'm getting, it will not return this collection row.

Comment: add your sqlfiddle in the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function find_in_set :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f90/13)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE collections (
id int,
uid int,
parent int,
title varchar(255),
inspids varchar(255),
private int,
collabs varchar(255),
ord int,
tstamp varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE inspirations (
id int,
uid int,
image varchar(255),
filters varchar(255),
caption varchar(255),
keywords varchar(255),
tstamp varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO collections SET id='100', uid='12', title='A collection example', inspids='2742,123,42',private='0',collabs='',ord='0',tstamp='1523272320';
INSERT INTO inspirations SET id='2742', uid='47', keywords='blabla,bright,test';
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT collections.id,collections.uid,title,inspids,private,collections.tstamp FROM collections
LEFT JOIN inspirations ON find_in_set(inspirations.id, collections.inspids) > 0
WHERE collections.uid = "12"
AND inspirations.keywords LIKE "%bright%"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f90/13/0)**:

```
|  id | uid |                title |     inspids | private |     tstamp |
|-----|-----|----------------------|-------------|---------|------------|
| 100 |  12 | A collection example | 2742,123,42 |       0 | 1523272320 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I need!